# Bootstrap modal, trap tabs keys

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, accessibility

I'm making a page that has to be AA accessible. In one part we have a bootstrap modal, when it opens I want to tab only within it, without tabbing outside of it. Currently, when I keep tabbing, it tabs elements on the background of the modal.

How can I make it such that it traps the tabs and if the user keeps tabbing, it'll only tab inside the modal?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style property `tabindex:-1` for all elements you do not wish to be able to be tabbed to. Thus, you will restrict tabbing to inside the modal.

Comment: You mean HTML property. tabindex is not part of the CSS spec (Style).